# Android selector not working in tabhost

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-selector

i have made a simple tabhost demo for learning purpose,i have made it successfully and running it as well,But my problem is images which i have put in drawable should come as mentioned in selectors but its not working..its not even showing images..!my code is:
**main.java**

```
package com.example.tabhostdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TabHost;


public class TabHostActivity extends TabActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_host);
         Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
         TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
         TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
         Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

         // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
         intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HomeActivity.class);
         spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("home")
         .setIndicator("HOME", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.home))
         .setContent(intent);
         tabHost.addTab(spec);

         // Do the same for the other tabs

         intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AboutActivity.class);
         spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("about")
         .setIndicator("ABOUT", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.about))
         .setContent(intent);
         tabHost.addTab(spec);


         intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ContactActivity.class);
         spec = tabHost
         .newTabSpec("contact")
         .setIndicator("CONTACT",
         res.getDrawable(R.drawable.contact))
         .setContent(intent);
         tabHost.addTab(spec);

         //set tab which one you want open first time 0 or 1 or 2
         tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);


         }

         }
```

**selectors**
**home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home1"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home2" />
</selector>
```

**contact**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/contact1"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/contact2" />
</selector>
```

**about.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/about1"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/about2" />
</selector>
```

Comment: please don't use tabhost it's depricated, try to use fragment tab with new features

Comment: please suggest me for my existing code..bro

Comment: check out this [link for ref](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-navigation-tabs-containing-listview-to-action-bar-in-android/)

Comment: @abhishesh-please suggest me for my code..!

Comment: For people coming here TabHost in NOT depricated, however TabActivity is.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html     But it would be best to use FragmentTabHost  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way.

```
spec.setIndicator("HOME", setImageResource(R.drawable.home))
```

It will work great.

Either you have to used this [example](http://adilsoomro.blogspot.in/2011/06/iphone-like-tabs-in-android.html).

Really great.

Comment: @jigar see example link may be helpful.

Comment: @Harshid this doesn't work for me, there is no `setImageResource` method...as far as I know that's a `ImageView` method, and not even static...