# Change tab icon for a specific tab from fragment android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabs, android-tabactivity

MainActivity is an actionbar tabswipe fragmentactivity with 5 fragments.  How can one change specific tab icon for example, icon at 3rd position while swiping to position 3 without affecting other tab icon.  tabs.setIcon() work but while swiping to other position the tab icon change to previous one. Is there a way to change only a specific tab icon from fragment.

```
    public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
implements ActionBar.TabListener, OnClickListener {

    public static ActionBar actionBar;
    // Titre des tabs

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Crashlytics.start(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;


        customActionBar();



        View tabView = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tabview, null);

        TextView tabText = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.tabText);
        //tabText.setText("Home");      tabText.setText("Home");

        ImageView tabImage = (ImageView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.tabIcon);

        tabImage.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.home));
        // Images des onglets

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(tabView)
                .setTabListener(this));

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.offer)
                .setTabListener(this));

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.plumeactionbar)
                .setTabListener(this));


        if (CommonUtilities.pref.GetPreferences("hasFavoris").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){

            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.bookmark_yellow)
                    .setTabListener(this));

        } else {

            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.bookmark)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }


        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                // System.out.println("onpageselected");
                if (position == 1 && TabsPagerAdapter.getPage() == 4) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                } else {
                    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
                if (position == 0) {
                    CommonUtilities.offset = 0;
                    setOnBackPressedListener(null);
                }
                System.out.println("ITEM_POSITION_THREE_NOTCALLED: "+position);

                if (position==3){

                    //System.out.println("ITEM_POSITION_THREE_CALLED: "+position);
                   // MyAnnoncesFragment myAnnoncesFragment = new MyAnnoncesFragment();
                    LocalBroadcastManager lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
                    Intent i = new Intent("TAG_REFRESH");
                    lbm.sendBroadcast(i);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (imm != null && AddOffersFragment.edit_AddTitre != null)
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                            AddOffersFragment.edit_AddTitre.getWindowToken(), 0);

                InputMethodManager imm2 = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (imm2 != null && NotLoggedFragment3.edit_pwd != null)
                    imm2.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                            NotLoggedFragment3.edit_pwd.getWindowToken(), 0);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });


    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        mtab=tab;

        if (hasFavoris){

            if (tab.getPosition()==3){

                tab.setIcon(R.drawable.bookmark_yellow);

            } 
        }

        if (isLogged){

            if (tab.getPosition()==4){
                tab.setIcon(R.drawable.user_blue);
            } 

        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    public void switchToTab(int tab) {
    }

    public void setOnBackPressedListener(
            OnBackPressedListener onBackPressedListener) {
        this.onBackPressedListener = onBackPressedListener;
        System.out.println("Main Activity : set on back pressed listener");
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (onBackPressedListener != null) {
            System.out.println("Main Activity : Delegation : doback");
            onBackPressedListener.doBack();
        } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() > 0) {
            System.out
            .println("Main Activity : ViewPager -> setcurrentitem at 0");
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Main Activity : renvoi au super");
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item_search:
            switch (TabsPagerAdapter.getPage()) {
            case 0:
                ResearchFragment.domaine = "Offre";
                break;
            case 1:
                ResearchFragment.domaine = "Trades";
                break;
            case 2:
                ResearchFragment.domaine = "Jobs";
                break;
            case 3:
                ResearchFragment.domaine = "Rencontres";
                break;
            }
            TabsPagerAdapter.setPage(4);
            ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mAdapter.startUpdate(mPager);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mAdapter.finishUpdate(mPager);
            mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static void refresh() {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }




    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // playServicesHelper.checkPlayServices();
    }

    public void customActionBar(){

        View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.action_bar_custom, null); // layout which contains your button.

        imCloseButton = 
                (ImageView)customNav.findViewById(R.id.imCloseButton);

        menuInfoButton = 
                (ImageView)customNav.findViewById(R.id.menuInfoButton);


        imCloseButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        menuInfoButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        actionBar.setCustomView(customNav);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (v.getId()){


        case R.id.imCloseButton:

            IsTaskIsRunning.renewClass();
            finish();

            break;


        case R.id.menuInfoButton:

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InfoFragment.class);
            startActivity(i);

            break;

        }
    }




}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183073/android-selector-not-working-in-tabhost

Comment: use this selector only for third tab.

Comment: ok but spec.setIndicator("HOME", setImageResource(R.drawable.home)) is for tabhost

Comment: R.drawable.home is a selector it will help.